# select, copy and paste range of rows based on a date value in a cell in a sorted by date list

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with some VBA in Excel to find a particular cell value (i.e today's date) and then based on that criteria select, copy and paste a range of rows into another worksheet based on the criteria that they are in the past or future. My worksheet is sorted ASC by date and have read a number of posts simillar to this problem but I didn't solve on my own so don't know if my problem is lack of expertise in working with dates, or that all the threads I read had slightly different requirements.

A sample of the source worksheet looks like this;

```
givenName   RegistrationStartDate
Kirstie     1/07/2010
Momena      12/01/2011
Seyedkazem  18/01/2011
Christie    3/02/2011
Jakub       8/02/2011
Steven      11/07/2011
Patrina     13/07/2011
Gregory     14/07/2011
Fatima      15/07/2011
Thomas      18/07/2011
Ala         **19/07/2011**
Anne        31/07/2011
Umair       1/08/2011
Laura       2/08/2011
```

And I need help with VBA to find today's date 19/07/2011 and paste this into a **'in the past'** worksheet;

```
givenName   RegistrationStartDate
Kirstie     1/07/2010
Momena      12/01/2011
Seyedkazem  18/01/2011
Christie    3/02/2011
Jakub       8/02/2011
Steven      11/07/2011
Patrina     13/07/2011
Gregory     14/07/2011
Fatima      15/07/2011
Thomas      18/07/2011
```

and **'in the future'** worksheet

```
givenName   RegistrationStartDate
Anne        31/07/2011
Umair       1/08/2011
Laura       2/08/2011
```

I guess what might have been adding to my grief is that I specifically don't need any rows with today's date. Once I get this sorted out I will be adding logic to the 'what date is it now' criteria (i.e 28 days before and after today's date) and copy/pasting rows based on that. I think if some kind guru can help me with the above, I should be okay from there.

Best Regards

Larry

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question, the function to get the current date (i.e. the system date which hopefully is the same), you use the `Date` function.

Now you process he list and compare each date with the system date;

- dates < sysdate are past
- dates > sysdate are future
- dates = sysdate are ignored

if your dates in the table contain time information, you must use `Int(yourtabledate)` to get rid of the time, because `02.08.2011 08:12 > 02.08.2011` (with implicit time `00:00`) and would therefore go to future which you don't want.

For ther rest ... if you don't know how to fomulate a loop across a table in VBA, post a specific question.

Cheers
Mike